# Javascript Touch properties

Tags: javascript, android, ios, touch

I'm writing an application that is supposed to run on a PC browser and a mobile device browser, be it a phone or a tablet.
I'm using 9 canvas elements on a page on which I want to perform operations but the thing is this:

The library I'm using for canvas allows me to use and read a property called 'layer' (either layerX and layerY) so that each "canvas" element is on a different layer (although I'm not telling explicitly that it is a new layer, everything works fine).

But when I came to test on the mobile devices, and accordingly to [this](http://www.sitepen.com/blog/2011/12/07/touching-and-gesturing-on-iphone-android-and-more/) article, the touch devices don't have this property, which causes the application not to work as expected, ie, nothing happens on touch and the touch arguments are empty.

So now I have a problem, I either use the 'client' property but I can perform actions only on the first drawn canvas element or if I let it to use 'layer' nothing happens.

How can I get around this problem? Shouldn't I be able to use the 'layer' property since the library for canvas allows me to have that property? Or to use it I should explicitly declare that each canvas element is a new layer?

Best Regards,

Comment: I don't completely understand your problem, though if it helps, `click` events work almost identically on both touchscreens and pcs.

Comment: Well, the problem is that I lose all touch functionality on mobile devices with touchscreen if I try to read the x and y coords through the 'layer' property. If I use the 'client' property everything works fine with one big exception, I'm not using a single canvas on a page, it's a grid of 9 canvases and so the 'client' property is only available to the first canvas "draw" on screen and can't do anything fot the other 8. So, the 'layer' property is only available on desktop functinality

Comment: @JeffreySweeney, btw, read the article and I think you'll quickly understand what I'm talking about